# Add vulkan support with min sdk16

Tags: android, vulkan

I would like to make an app, can run on a wide range of devices, and if Vulkan is supported, than it  renders with Vulkan. So I set the target SDK version to 26 and the min sdk version to 16. Is there a way to use Vulkan this way, or I have to make two different apps.

When im using min sdk 16 I get this, error message:

`Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

and nothing else.

but if im building with minsdk 26 it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't link against libvulkan.so since it won't be present on most devices before API 26. So instead you need to load it manually at runtime:

```
struct VulkanFuncs {
    PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr GetInstanceProcAddr;
    // ...
};

VulkanFuncs vk;
libvulkan = dlopen("libvulkan.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
if (!libvulkan) { /* must be on API < 26 */ }
vk.GetInstanceProcAddr = (PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr)dlsym(libvulkan, "vkGetInstanceProcAddr");
// use vkGetInstanceProcAddr(NULL, ...) to get address of other "global" funcs
// after creating the instance, use vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, ...)
// to get address of all other Vulkan funcs
```

Comment: Note that even on API 26, not all devices support Vulkan. So you'll be able to create a VkInstance, but vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices might return zero devices. Whatever your fallback path is, you'll want to use it in that case too.